# How to read parts of a file into an object

Tags: c#

I have a file that I would like to scan and get the sections into a custom object.

The file looks like that:

```
[Student]
Name=John
LastName=Doe 
Username=user1
Password=pass1

[Teacher]
Name=Jane
LastName=Doe
Username=user2
Password=pass2

[Manager]
Name=Jason
LastName=Doe
Username=user3
Password=pass3
```

And I have a `Profile` class that looks like that:

```
public class Profile
{
    public string studentName       { get; set; }
    public string studentLastName   { get; set; }
    public string studentUsername   { get; set; }
    public string studentPassword   { get; set; }
    public string teacherName       { get; set; }
    public string teacherLastName   { get; set; }
    public string teacherUsername   { get; set; }
    public string teacherPassword   { get; set; }
}
```

So, I need to get only the student and the teacher into the profile object. Here is how I started:

```
public Profile readFile(string filename)
{
     var profile = new Profile();

     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
     {
         while (!sr.EndOfStream)
         {
             String line = sr.ReadLine();
             if (line != null && line.Contains("Student"))
             {
                 // and I am stuck here, not sure how to find 
                 // the next lines, so i can take the values
                 // and put them in the profile 
              }

              if (line != null && line.Contains("Teacher"))
              {
                 // and I am stuck here, not sure how to find 
                 // the next lines, so i can take the values
                 // and put them in the profile 
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: You could use `File.ReadLine` and take only the first 11 lines to process. If you have multiple such blocks of data in the file, you can just adjust your logic to skip over the last 6 lines of each block (to ignore the Manager data)

Comment: I suppose that taking the first 11 lines wouldn´t be the right way, because the file will expand and contain different numbers of teachers and students. Am I right?

Comment: does it's a text file? you can split it according the '[' and ']'

Comment: @christoph Yes, I've edited my comment. However, OP needs to confirm if the file will always follow the structure given. If you have one Student followed by n Teachers or vice-versa, that has to be treated differently.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Taking the first 11 lines is not a good idea if the order changes in future.

Comment: @shree.pat18 I cannot guarantee that the order will be the always the same, so the best for me is to be able to identify the `[Student]` and the `[Teacher]`

Comment: there is a block of `student`, 'teacher' etc. or it's can be mix ('s', 't', 's', 'm')?

Comment: @AsfK normally it is, but it could also be a '[Teacher]' followed by a '[Student]'

Comment: http://nini.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var p=new Profile();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        String line = sr.ReadLine();
        if (line != null && line.Contains("Student"))
        {
            p.studentName=GetLineValue(sr.ReadLine());
            p.studentLastName=GetLineValue(sr.ReadLine());
            p.studentUsername=GetLineValue(sr.ReadLine());
            p.studentPassword=GetLineValue(sr.ReadLine());
        }

        if (line != null && line.Contains("Teacher"))
        {
            p.teacherName=GetLineValue(sr.ReadLine());
            p.teacherLastName=GetLineValue(sr.ReadLine());
            p.teacherUsername=GetLineValue(sr.ReadLine());
            p.teacherPassword=GetLineValue(sr.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
private string GetLineValue(string line)
{
   return line.Substring(line.IndexOf('=')+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit of pseudocode that should get you started:

```
if (line != null && line.Contains("Student"))
{
  var temp = new Student();

  do {
      string temp_line = String line = sr.ReadLine();

      if //temp_line is empty
      {     
        // you got the line. split on "="

        // assign the student property to the value
        // you'll have to use a bit of reflection here, but shouldn't be too hard


      }

    } while // not empty string (which means you're ready for the next object)
}
```

I'd probably break them into methods that will simply fill each object (student/ teacher, etc ...)

The benefits is that you don't depend on order, and you can add code that will go "oh, that property does not exist, skip it" if you'd like ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection. Like this

```
    public static Profile readFile(string filename)
    {
        var profile = new Profile();
        var properties = typeof(Profile).GetProperties().ToDictionary(q => q.Name, q => q);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            String mode = "";

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                String line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line == "[Student]")
                {
                    mode = "student";

                    // and I am stuck here, not sure how to find 
                    // the next lines, so i can take the values
                    // and put them in the profile 
                }
                else if (line == "[Teacher]")
                {
                    mode = "teacher";
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                    var nameValues = line.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
                    if (nameValues.Length < 2)
                        continue;

                    var key = mode + nameValues[0];

                    if (properties.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        var value = nameValues[1];
                        properties[key].SetValue(profile, value);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return profile;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can found the braces, like this:

```
class memberLocation
{
    public int start, end;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        memberLocation student, teacher, manager;
        student = new memberLocation();
        teacher = new memberLocation();
        manager = new memberLocation();

        String filePath = "data.txt";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
        String fileData = sr.ReadToEnd();

        student.start = fileData.IndexOf("[Student]");
        teacher.start = fileData.IndexOf("[Teacher]");
        manager.start = fileData.IndexOf("[Manager]");

        student.end = fileData.IndexOf(']', student.start + 9) - 9; // [Student] length = 9 - [Teacher] length
        teacher.end = fileData.IndexOf(']', teacher.start + 9) - 9; // [Teacher] length = 9
        manager.end = fileData.IndexOf(']', manager.start + 9) - 9; // [Manager] length = 9

        String studentStr, teacherStr, managerStr;
        if (student.end > 0)
            studentStr = fileData.Substring(student.start, student.end - student.start);
        else
            studentStr = fileData.Substring(student.start);
        if (teacher.end > 0)
            teacherStr = fileData.Substring(teacher.start, teacher.end - teacher.start);
        else
            teacherStr = fileData.Substring(teacher.start);
        if (manager.end > 0)
            managerStr = fileData.Substring(manager.start, manager.end - manager.start);
        else
            managerStr = fileData.Substring(manager.start);
    }
}
```